# Where can I find the Senate amendments to Bill C-6?

Tags: canada, reference-request

Where can I find the text of the Senate amendments to Bill C-6? I would like the version of the bill that was sent back to the House of Commons after being passed on May 3.

I've only been able to find [the version originally passed by the House.](http://www.parl.ca/DocumentViewer/en/42-1/bill/C-6/third-reading)

Answer (score 1):

You can find the text of the amendments in the [Senate debates](https://www.parl.ca/LegisInfo/en/bill/42-1/C-6).  It's a bit tedious, but it's all there.

In this debate, for example, someone proposes an [amendment](https://sencanada.ca/en/content/sen/chamber/421/debates/104db_2017-03-09-e?language=e#46).

Of course, then you have to go through the proceeding and find whether the amendment passed, whether another amendment superseded it, etc.  But there's a finite amount of material to go through.